# Why do I not have a global neo4j object although I integrated the javascript-driver?

Tags: javascript, neo4j

I have a problem when trying to ask my neo4j databse with the Javascript-driver. I researched a lot, but didn't found any solution.

When running my code, I get that error: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'basic' of undefined. But why is there no neo4j object? I followed the doc on https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j-javascript-driver and I don't know what i did wrong.

`<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/neo4j-driver@1.5.3/lib/browser/neo4j-web.min.js"></script>`

````
<script>
    // Create a driver instance, for the user neo4j with password neo4j.
    // It should be enough to have a single driver per database per application.

    let driver = neo4j.driver('bolt://localhost', neo4j.auth.basic('neo4j', 'password'))

    // Create a session to run Cypher statements in.
    // Note: Always make sure to close sessions when you are done using them!
    let session = driver.session();

    // the Promise way, where the complete result is collected before we act on it:
    session
        .run('MERGE (t:Topics {name : {nameParam} }) RETURN t.name AS name LIMIT 20', {
            nameParam: 'Magic'
        })
        .then(function (result) {
            result.records.forEach(function (record) {
                console.log(record.get('name'));
            });
            session.close();
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });

    // Close the driver when application exits.
    // This closes all used network connections.
    driver.close();
</script>```
````

Comment: It's neo4j.auth that's undefined, not neo4j

Comment: It looks like you installed an old version of the driver?  I think they're at 4.2 but you're using 1.5.3?